# Low TR first mash

Tags: fermentation, mash

I am first time distiller, my first mash is seven days in. The mash started out foamy and bubbling now today the foam is gone and no more bubbling. I checked TR but it’s ready 0, I am wondering what to do next, add more yeast,yeast nutrient, heat I’m not sure if this is how it should be or if it is ruined. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does TR mean?

Comment: Short for tralles or alcohol by volume. I’m think I may have not waited long enough for fermentation.